# Temporary profile on remote desktop server

Tags: remote-desktop-services, user-profile

We have 6 RD Servers (2012 and 2008) and on all of them users sometimes get assigned a temporary profile.

In Eventlog we can always see Event ID 1600

Das Profil kann nicht von <domain>\files\RD_Profiles nach C:\Users kopiert werden. Es steht nicht genügend Speicherplatz auf dem Datenträger zur Verfügung.

my english translation:

profile could not be copied from <domain>\files\RD_Profiles to C:\Users. There is not enough disk space available.

The weird thing is that we have more than enough space left (around 100GB on each RDS and about 1TB on the fileserver). And the problem does not always occur, for example today 3 users had this problem (out of ~100).

Any suggestions?

Comment: and on the client that it requests it? do you limited maybe via a quota the space can be used, is the space monitored?

Comment: no errors on the fileserver.
no quotas that I could find either. No quota on the fileserver (fsrm) and no quota on the rd servers (rd services and windows)

the space is monitored with PRTG. Lowest we ever got in the last month was 12.3% free space left

Comment: we need more information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it (gib alles was du hast)

Comment: I think I found the problem. For some reason someone decided to do a fsrm quota on all the rd servers directly on c:\users, instead of just doing it on the roaming profiles.
Didn't even cross my mind that the old IT would do it this way around when it 10 times more work

Answer (score 0):

Basically my first assumption was correctly ;-)

If Windows tells you, you have not enough space

the common Issues or Solvings are:

- Check the Filesystem for corrcuption (CHKDSK)
- Check the Filesystem of the Host, if its a VM if the space is not exhausted (Thin-Provising)
- Sometimes just a simple Reboot fix the issue.
- Specially on a Windows Server: Check with the common tools, if a FSR-Quota has been set.

the Answer for this question is the last option

Answer (score 0):

We recently resolved this same issue by disabling compression on the folder properties of the share.. super random. it generates a resource issue in the logs for it thats ambiguous at best as you discovered. You would think MS could include this in their setup KB as a side note.

hope this helps someone as I spent a week trying to fix it.